# How to compare an array against a list of UI elements in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

In my Cypress tests, I am trying to compare an array of objects *(names)* returned to me from a SQL query against a list of elements on my UI *(the same names)*.

Here is my initial attempt at comparing the values:

```
import searchResultsPage from "../page_objects/searchResults.page"

cy.task('queryDb', `SELECT * FROM myTable where name like '%${queryInput}%';`).then(result => {
    for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
        searchResultsPage.name(i+1).should('have.text', `${result[i].name}`)
    }
})
```

Here is my page object file - `searchResults.page.js`:

```
class searchResultsPage {

    name(index) { return cy.get(`#mat-option-${index+1} > .mat-option-text`) }

}

module.exports = new searchResultsPage()
```

The problem with the above code is that the lists contain the exact same values, however they are not in the same order.

The database can store the names like ***Adam, Bill, Charlie***, but the UI may display them like ***Charlie, Adam Bill***.

The test should pass if the same records are in both lists, regardless of their order.

I attempted to re-order both arrays alphabetically below, & compare the values. The array from the SQL query (`result`) is sorting as expected. However, the array of HTML elements (`myArray`) is not sorting alphabetically:

```
cy.task('queryDb', `SELECT * FROM myTable where name like '%${queryInput}%';`).then(result => {

        let myArray;

        cy.get('mat-option').then(elements => {

            myArray = Array.from(elements, element => element.innerText);
            
            cy.log(myArray)

            myArray.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.name < b.name) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (a.name > b.name) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });

            cy.log('HTML array:')

            for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                cy.log(myArray[i])
            }

            cy.log('*********')

            result.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.name < b.name) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (a.name > b.name) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });

            cy.log('SQL array:')

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                cy.log(result[i].name)
            }

            cy.log('*********')

        }).then(() => {

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                cy.log(result[i].name)
                cy.log(myArray[i])
                expect(result[i].name).to.deep.eq(myArray[i])
            }

        })
    })
```

Can someone please explain why the `result` array isn't sorting alphabetically above?

Comment: You could gather the HTML elements `innerText` & sort them alphabetically before the assertion. There's many ways to solve this, this is just one

Comment: Hi @ManuelAbascal Thanks for your suggestion. I have attempted to sort alphabetically & updated my question with my effort. I'm able to sort one array, but am facing issues with the other.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to sort it yourself, you can use set membership

```js
cy.task('queryDb', `SELECT * FROM myTable...`).then(result => {
  cy.get('mat-option')
    .should(elements => {
      const elementNames = Array.from(elements, element => element.innerText))
      const resultNames = result.map(r => r.name)

      expect(resultNames).to.have.members(elementNames)  

    })
})
```

Using `.should()` will allow Cypress to retry to the assertion (in case the elements are still loading).

Ref: [Testing Arrays and Objects with Chai.js](https://medium.com/building-ibotta/testing-arrays-and-objects-with-chai-js-4b372310fe6d)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to split sort and join both the sql and the html texts

```js
  it("does some checking", () => {
    // this would come from the sql task
    const myExpectation = "Charlie, Adam, Bill";

    // split, trim, sort, and join the string
    const cleanSql = str => str.split(/[\,]/gi).map(s => s.trim()).sort().join(",");
    
    // function uses `then` to get texts and sort and join it
    const getNames = (index) => {
      return cy
        .get(`#mat-option-${index + 1} > .mat-option-text`)
        .then((chainer) => {
          const values = [...chainer.map((el) => chainer[el].innerText)];
          return values.sort().join(",");
        });
    };

    // uses `equal` because the returned value is a string (have.text wouldn't work on it)
    getNames(1).should("equal", cleanSql(myExpectation));
  });
```

This assumes your html looks like this

```html
<div id="mat-option-2">
  <div class="mat-option-text">Bill</div>
  <div class="mat-option-text">Adam</div>
  <div class="mat-option-text">Charlie</div>
</div>
```

I'm using static `myExpectation` for local testability. You would, obviously, have to adapt that to your setup.